# How to open an existing Joomla project?

Tags: joomla3.0

I got a joomla project has been implemented by someone else. He gave me user name and password for the admin panel. But I can't access the content of the web page.

Comment: Ask them to put your user under a User Group that allows editing/publishing content (Administrator or Publisher would do it).

Answer (score 0):

In Order to get full control of your Joomla site you should ask for Super Administrator access level.
Only an existing Super Administrator can grant such access.